# Insert data from Table1 to Table2 in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I have two tables, `table1` has 2 columns and `table2` has 3 columns.

I would like to insert values of `table1 col1 and table1 col2` into `table2 of one column.

Here is data from `table1`:

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║  Col1  ║  Col2  ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║ Value1 ║ Value2 ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

Insert that into a `table2` row: like

```
╔════════╦
║ Value1 ║
╠════════╣
║ Value2 ║
╚════════╝
```

How to do this with SQL?

Comment: Ever heard of a thing called punctuation? I cannot understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy each in a different row use:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1;
```

Or One by One

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1)
SELECT col1 FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table2 (col2)
SELECT col2 FROM table1;
```

If you want to concatenate in the same row use

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col3)
    SELECT col1 + col2 FROM table1;
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col3)
   SELECT col1 || col2 FROM table1;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: i want to no  concatenate the two column. i want a require this two column values insert in table as a separate row in another table

Comment: Ok, then you have to do this way: <br> INSERT INTO table2 (col1)
SELECT col1 FROM table1;<br> INSERT INTO table2 (col2)
SELECT col2 FROM table1;

Please vote the responses

Comment: hi David,  Thanks, but i need a using single query.

Comment: I have edited the first post, there is the response there, please select as solution the response if it helps you.